# Why I can only choose java 8 or 11 when I create SprintBoot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When I create a spring boot project following tutorial, I can only choose java version 8 or 11.

I have already installed jdk 7 and jre 7 on my Mac.

Then I start a springboot project using idea like following steps:
1. Create New Project
2.select spring initializer
3.set project sdk to be jdk 7 
4. when I step into "Project Metadata" page, I can only select "java version" 8 or 11. I want to select java 7, but the scroll down window only shows 8 or 11.

Comment: have you added the java7 environment to your IDE?µ

Comment: Because those are the 2 java versions that the Spring Initializer supports. The wizard in IntelliJ uses the metadata from the initializer to create the actual screens. Next to that if you are using Spring Boot 2.1 the minimal java version is 8.

Comment: Java 7 is history. Replace it asap.

Comment: Is there some specific reason why you installed Java 7 and not the latest version?

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot 2 is built on top of Spring 5 and Spring 5 requires at least Java 8.

If you need to build for Java 7 you must use Spring Boot 1.

The reason for 8 and 11 is that these version will have long term support where 9 and 10 will not.

Comment: To complement that answer, it is also about supported versions: Java 7 is EOLed since April 2015, that's more than three years ago. We don't see a reason why you would want to get started on a new project with an unsupported Java version. If you really need this, you have to select Spring Boot 1 and change the java version manually when the project has been generated.